# Is it possible to create a credential provider with its own authentication rules on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-authentication, credential-providers, ssp

I've read a lot about credential providers but haven't been able to come to a consensus on whether I can create my own way to authenticate into the system, such as a PIN code. I believe that this Credential Provider does not directly transfer the password, but uses other methods, such as SSP?
I would be extremely grateful if you could point me to implemented examples or documentation. Thank you.

I have read win docs, but suddenly can't understand way to make what I want.

Comment: Credential provider only collect data from user and pass it to system. System pass this data to authentication package. Authentication package must understand serialisation from cred provider. If you want not known foormat, you need implement own auth package too